# Testing a Linux router on Laptop with one NIC

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, routing, router

So, I have [these instructions](http://www.databook.bz/?page_id=697) on converting my Linux machine to a router using (enable IP forwarding, NAT). Now my laptop has only one NIC and I want to test this setup. Any ideas how I can do this?
Do I need to use Linux in VM and there is no other way? Or is there a network config that can show routing behaviour with one interface only?
(Please give details if required, I am not very good on linux)

Note: If there is a tool, I need any that works, not the very best in one's opinion.

Comment: How to test what exactly? What are these instructions? Why don't you just follow them?

Comment: http://www.databook.bz/?page_id=697

These are the instructions, but it uses 2 NICs, I have one only, so most probably a VM based solution may work, I am not sure though. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: In addition, I want my router to work with arbitrary number of interfaces, which I think above mentioned settings will do. Please suggest if otherwise.

Comment: Considering your two questions, I think you should first test your environment on a virtual machine, on a virtual network. There you will be able to test all the configuration options easily. See for example http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 2):

If you read the instructions, it says clearly:

> Three things are required to make a Linux box into a router. From a hardware standpoint **you need two NICs.**

Hence, unless you use a virtual machine when you can create as many virtual NICs you like, no, you can't make your system a router.

Comment: There is another config, called 'router on a stick', can I use Linux router to do that? It requires one interface for physical routers. And probably it will tell if machine is working as a router or not?